# how can I read a text file from online from my wp7 application?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Im new app developing, beware. I want my windows phone app to access a text file from my dropbox and display the information in a textblock by binding it. Does anyone know how can I accomplish this?

or if anyone knows another site where I can upload my text file instead of dropbox, please share. I just don't want to hardcore all the info to the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to find an existing `API` that meets your requirements. That would be:

- .NET Dropbox Client Library
- Compatibility with WP

Some Dropbox client libraries are recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576923/dropbox-com-api-for-net).

It looks that both [sharpbox](http://sharpbox.codeplex.com/) and [dropnet](https://github.com/dkarzon/DropNet) are WP7 compatible.

Use them to get information about the file / to get the file.

Also if you are new to WP7 programming you might want to check some of these resources:

- [MVVM in WP7](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg521153%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)
- [Code samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744%28v=vs.92%29.aspx#BKMK_QuickStarts)

Answer (score 0):

http://pastebin.com/ is a great place to dump text files, or a public FTP server, maybe someones website it doesnt really matter for the purpose here anywhere is alright aslong as you can call a single URL to the file without having to authenticate or do some APIs to access a store.

personally I would just upload the Text File anywhere here is an example of my paste

http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=a0TLDiaM

make sure you gather the RAW link to the file as opposed to the standard webpage

then use a Webclient to downloadStringAsync, for examples on this see

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/pages/silverlight-tutorial-part-3-using-networking-to-retrieve-data-and-populate-a-datagrid.aspx